# why is adding a carraige return to file java not work?

Tags: java, file

The following is a simple code in java that just appends a new line to a existing file. My problem is that I want it to add a carraige return for each new line. The first line the return is skipped. I have even tried "\n" but it still does not work. I have run the code couple times.

NOTE:This code does not belong to me. I saw it on a forum and am trying to work with it. I need this type of file update for my project.

```
try
{
    File filename = new File("testFile.txt");
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename,true)); 
    String newLine = "new Line";
    writer.println("\r" + newLine);//appends the string to the file
    writer.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The file is the following:

```
Hello worldnew Line
new Line
new Line
```

But the file I want should be:

```
Hello world
new Line
new Line
new Line
```

Comment: It *does* write the character - open the file in hex. However, most editors/consoles *won't* display a lonely "\r" as a "new line". The UNIX line separator is "\n" and, for Windows/web it's "\r\n".

Comment: Try using a binary OutputStream, I think the "Writer" family of classes converts "\r" to "\n" silently.

Comment: Try using System.getProperty("line.separator");

Answer (score 3):

The PrintWriter's `println()` methods will add the appropriate sequence of newline characters for the platform. And no platform that I know uses `\r` as a sequence. Just use

```
writer.println();
writer.println(newLine);
```

or

```
writer.println();
writer.print(newLine);
```

if you don't want a newline sequence after the line you're adding.

Comment: I previously had println("\n" + newLine) but this did not work. why do I need to do println() twice?

Comment: Yes indeed :) Is anyone still using MacOS 9?

Comment: @user3052985. But on Windows, the sequence is `\r\n`.

Comment: (Write.exe will also understand just "\n", IIRC)

Comment: @JBNizet Some of us have a few older Macs around. My kids like the retro games. ;)

Comment: The good news is that println will probably generate \r for MacOS 9 (if you can still find a JRE for MacOS 9)

Comment: @JBNizet \r\n makes the file double spaced?

Comment: @user3052985: what do you mean? on windows, the native newline sequence is \r\n, and println will thus insert that sequence.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts. The println and print is what I went with. Its working the way I wanted. So I get that println terminates the current line and then the print adds to the new line. However I am still a bit confused about why the \n was not working. Nevertheless thank you all for your help.